# VueUse useDark() does not trigger computed or watch

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, composable, vueuse

```
import { useDark } from '@vueuse/core';

const isDark = useDark();

watch(isDark, () => {
  console.log('dark mode changed'); // does not trigger watch
}, { deep: true })

const scheme = computed(isDark, () => {
   options: isDark.value ? 'dark' : 'light' // does not trigger update of scheme
})

</script>``
```

##### But, custom composable like below do trigger updates of watches and computed. Also, this vueuse library returns the type WritableComputedRef, I don't know if that is the issue here.

```
const isDarkMode = ref(false);

export function useDarkMode() {
  const KEY = 'dark-mode';
  isDarkMode.value = (localStorage.getItem(KEY) ?? '') === 'dark';

  function toggleDarkMode() {
    isDarkMode.value = !isDarkMode.value;

    localStorage.setItem(KEY, isDarkMode.value ? 'dark' : '');
  }

  return {
    isDarkMode,
    toggleDarkMode,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

neither watch or computed did it for me. I rather used this function, as it is already [documented](https://vueuse.org/core/useDark/#configuration).

```
import { useDark } from '@vueuse/core'

const isDark = useDark({
  onChanged(dark: boolean) {
    // update the dom, call the API or something
    console.log('hello', dark)
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled trying to put the state of useDark `isDark` in pinia store and override the onChanged handler.. so based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/76173078/986160 answer I provide the code of my `DaskSwitch` component in case someone wants to do something similar and set the state in pinia using `setDark` action for example.

This way it can then be used through computed or watchers.

I also struggled to initialize isDark outside of my component (as shown in documentation) and also make it work with pinia which hasn't initialized outside of the component.. So the following syntax solves both of those issues as well.

```
<script setup>
import { useDark, useToggle } from '@vueuse/core'
import { useDataStore } from '@/stores/dataStore';
import { mapActions } from 'pinia'

</script>
<script>

export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isDark: false,
        toggleDark: () => {}
      }
    },
    beforeMount() {
      const isDark = useDark({
        selector: 'body',
        attribute: 'class',
        valueDark: 'dark',
        valueLight: 'light',
        onChanged: (dark) => {
          if (process.client) { // nuxt specific omit in case you use vue.js
            if (dark) {
              document.querySelector('body').classList.add('dark')
            } else {
              document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('dark')
            }
          this.setDark(dark)
          }
        }
      })
      this.toggleDark = useToggle(isDark)
    },
    methods: {
          ...mapActions(useDataStore, ['setDark']),
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="mode-toggle" @click="toggleDark()" >
            <div class="toggle">
                <div id="dark-mode" type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to use your watch like this:

```
watch(() => isDark, (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue);
})
```

regarding the computed I am not sure if it can work like that, I've never seen a computed being initialised like that.

it probably should look like this:

```
const state = computed(() => isDark.value ? 'dark' : 'light');
```

Comment: ```
watch(() => isDark, (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue);
})
```
This does not work. I have tried it. I believe this is a getter function and should be used when tracking changes in a reactive object.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, mainly because I tried to use it in many location, it just doesn't make sense I figured

```
const isDark = useDark()
const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark);

watch: {
    isDark: {
      handler(val) {
        useThemeConfigStore.setTheme(val == true ? "dark" : "light");
      },
    },
  },
```

I have simply remove on the other files, and just use pinia or vuex to watch over the state